# What are the use cases of the `name` property of the `RequestMapping` annotation in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Apologies, if you find this question dumb... I am new to Spring framework. I spent hours looking up an answer...

According to the official Spring Framework documentation, you can assign a name to a `RequestMapping` annotation using the `name` property.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#name--

So the question is what's the point of giving a name to a route mapping?

In Symfony framework, we can use the mapping name to generate a URL.

```php
class BlogController
{
    /**
     * @Route(name="BlogComments", path="blog/{blog}/comments/{page}")
     */
    public function listBlogComments(Blog blog, page)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then we can generate a URL based on the route name.

```php
// This will generate a string "blog/27/comments/1".
$url = $this->generateUrl('BlogComments', [
    'blog' => 27,
    'page' => 1
]);
```

This is possible thanks to the `Symfony\Component\Routing\Router` component.

The controller class can be written like the following in the Spring framework.

```java
@Controller
@ResponseBody
class BlogController {

    @RequestMapping(name="BlogComments", path="blog/{blog}/comments/{page}")
    public List<Comment> listBlogComments(@PathVariable Blog blog, @PathVariable Long page) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now how do I generate a URL based on the name of the mapping which is `"BlogComments"` in this case? Is there any Spring component or Service available as in the Symfony framework? What other possible use cases are available?

Comment: Are you telling how will you access by giving `name`, right ?

Comment: @AnishB.  In the Symfony example given above, the `name` value passed to the `@Route` annotation is used to generate a URL that maps to the route.  My question is essentially how we can accomplish the same thing in Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

> public abstract String name
>
> Assign a name to this mapping. Supported at the type level as well as
>   at the method level! When used on both levels, a combined name is
>   derived by concatenation with "#" as separator.

The key moment is When used on both levels

So you should assign a name for the controller as well  as well and it should start working.

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(name = "AdminController")
class BlogController {

    @RequestMapping(name="BlogComments", path="blog/{blog}/comments/{page}")
    public List<Comment> listBlogComments(@PathVariable Blog blog, @PathVariable Long page) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then you can access URL using #

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>

<a href="${s:mvcUrl('AdminController#BlogComments').arg("1","123").build()}">Get Person</a>
```

> Applications can build a URL to a controller method by name with the
>   help of the static method MvcUriComponentsBuilder#fromMappingName or
>   in JSPs through the "mvcUrl" function registered by the Spring tag
>   library.

Comment: what's the `url` function?

Comment: @user3858559 I have added the explanation for the `url` function available to the rest endpoint using the name. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It seems JSP is the only reason you'd ever want to use the `name` property of `RequestMapping` then? Given most people are using Thymleaf instead of JSP these days I guess it's a pretty obsolete property then?

Answer (score 1):

`@RequestMapping` annotation's name attribute can be used to assign a name to the mapping of controller class and method.

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(name = "BlogController")
class BlogController {

    @RequestMapping(name="BlogComments", path="blog/{name}")
    public List<Comment> listBlogComments(@PathVariable String name) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The Spring JSP tag library provides a function called mvcUrl that can be used to prepare links to controller methods based on this mechanism.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
...
<a href="${s:mvcUrl('BlogController#BlogComments').arg("test").buildAndExpand()}">Get Coments</a>
```